# Serving static files from Amazon S3 through Heroku

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn

I have a Python application which uses a lot of static files. I would like to store those static files on Amazon S3. When a user requests a file (such as a pdf), it will be served from S3. However, for cosmetic purposes I don't want to show the S3 URL in the address bar as I feel that it will only confuse the users. If a user were to download a file I wouldn't mind if the download URL display as S3, but for the purposes of files that will be viewed in browser I believe hiding the true URL makes sense.

Example: User views pdf file at http://www.example.com/view/myfile.pdf, where the server is infact pulling from an external url such as http://www.amazons3.com/user/file/file2.pdf

Please note that I am not doing this for security reasons. After some research I found that a server running Nginx would be able to mask the URL through "X-Accel-Redirect". However, this isn't really an option due to Heroku.

As Heroku handles routing, is there a way I can implement this "masking" just using Herokus platform?

I have seen a number of questions regarding serving static files, but nothing regarding URL masking.

My application stack is:

- Python Flask
- Gunicorn
- Heroku

Answer (score 1):

Make a route in your Flask app that takes a path and redirects to the appropriate S3 file.

```
@app.route('/s3/<path:path>')
def s3_file(path):
    return redirect('https://www.amazons3.com/user/file/{}'.format(path), code=301)
```

You can use `url_for` to build an appropriate url:

```
url_for('s3_file', path='file2.pdf')
```